# Existence of a "quasi-uniform" probability distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: pr.probability

Does there exist a probability distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that
for every integer $n\geq 1$, the probability that a random integer $x$
is divisible by $n$ equals $1/n$?

Henry Cohn has an argument why this is not possible, but it is not
completely rigorous. First, it is easy to see that we can assume that
the distribution is supported on the positive integers. Let  $p_n$ be
the probability of $n$. For any function $f$ on the positive integers
for which we get convergence, we have (by the assumption on $p_n$)
  $$ \sum_k p_k\sum_{n|k}f(n) = \sum_n \frac{f(n)}{n}. $$
Let $g(k)=\sum_{n|k} f(n)$. By Möbius inversion,
$f(n) = \sum_{k|n}g(k)\mu(n/k)$. Writing $n=mk$, the first equation
becomes
 $$ \sum_k p_k g(k) =\sum_k g(k)\sum_m \frac{\mu(m)}{mk}. $$
This should hold for all $g$ for which $\sum_n f(n)/n$ converges
absolutely, so it should follow that
   $$ p_k = \frac 1k\sum_m \frac{\mu(m)}{m}. $$
This is nonsense since first of all, $\sum_m \mu(m)/m =0$ (equivalent
to the prime number theorem), and even if we didn't know that, there's
no way $p_k$ can be proportional to $1/k$ since $\sum 1/k=\infty$.

This argument is not completely rigorous  since we have interchanged
sums and equated coefficients of $g(k)$ without justification. It's
also a problem that $\sum_m \mu(m)/m$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: What about a relaxed version: does there exist a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n \mu( n \mathbb{Z})$ is bounded away from $0$ and $+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. Let's restrict our attention to $\mathbb{N}$. The hypotheses imply that if $q$ is a prime, then the probability that a random positive integer is not divisible by $q$ is $1 - \frac{1}{q}$. They also imply that these events are independent. Now let $n$ be a positive integer. If $q_1, q_2, \dots$ is an enumeration of the primes not dividing $n$ it follows that

$$p_n \le \prod_{i=1}^m \left( 1 - \frac{1}{q_i} \right)$$

for all $m$. But taking $m \to \infty$ the RHS approaches $0$; contradiction. Note that this argument does not require the prime number theorem; we just need to know that the harmonic series diverges.

**Edit:** Here is a generalization which more completely rescues Henry Cohn's argument. Generalize the condition to being that the probability of a positive integer being divisible by $n$ is $\frac{1}{n^s}$, for some real number $s > 0$. This is equivalent to requiring that the probability is 1) multiplicative in $n$ and 2) monotonically decreasing.

It follows that if $q$ is prime, then the probability that the exponent of $q$ in the prime factorization of a random positive integer is exactly $k$ is

$$\frac{1}{q^{ks}} - \frac{1}{q^{(k+1)s}} = \frac{1}{q^{ks}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{q^s} \right).$$

We again have that for different primes $q$ these events are independent. Now, if $q_1, q_2, \dots$ is an enumeration of the primes and $n = \prod q_i^{k_i}$ is a positive integer, it follows that

$$p_n \le \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{q_i^{k_i s}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{q_i^s} \right).$$

for all $m$. If $s \le 1$ then the RHS converges to $0$ as $m \to \infty$ (this, again, does not require the prime number theorem) and we get a contradiction. If $s > 1$ then the RHS converges to

$$p_n = \frac{1}{n^s \zeta(s)}$$

and this is an equality because the RHS is the probability that a random positive integer has the same prime factorization as $n$.

There is a straightforward generalization where $\mathbb{N}$ is replaced by the set of nonzero ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$ and the probability of an ideal being divisible by an ideal $I$ is $\frac{1}{N(I)^s}$, where we get the Dedekind zeta function instead.

Comment: How do you get independence for different primes?  They are certainly pairwise independent, but I don't see how to deduce mutual independence for more than two primes.

Comment: @Henry: by hypothesis, the probability that a number is divisible by $m$ distinct primes $q_1, q_2, \dots q_m$ is the product of the probabilities that it's divisible by each of $q_1, q_2, \dots q_m$ separately. So the events of being divisible by different primes are independent, and hence so are their complements. Equivalently, if you like, it follows by repeated application of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Oops, I was being silly (and had somehow convinced myself this wasn't enough to get full independence for more than two).

Comment: In fact, this solution is often presented as a consequence of the Borel-Cantelli (second) Lemma:
letting $N$ be a random variable with the given law, the events $p|N$ with $p$ prime are independent by the very assumption, and of probability $1/p$ whose sum is infinite. Then with probability $1$, an infinite number of these events occur, which is not possible.

Comment: @Benoît: that's very nice! I'll further add that there actually is an object which behaves like that, namely Haar measure on the profinite integers. The probability that a profinite integer is divisible by $n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$, and then Borel-Cantelli shows that with probability $1$ a profinite integer is divisible by infinitely many primes (while my argument, equivalently, shows that the integers have measure zero in the profinite integers).

Comment: I don't think I follow your first argument, and I think whatever argument you give shouldn't work for finitely additive measures: Let $\mu$ be a translation-invariant finitely additive probability measure on $\mathbf{Z}$. Then $n\mathbf{Z}, n\mathbf{Z}+1, \dots, n\mathbf{Z}+n-1$ all must have the same measure, so $\mu(n\mathbf{Z})=1/n$.

Comment: Ah, I see now: $p_n$ is the probability of taking the value $n$, not the $n$th prime, and your argument shows that any finitely additive measure with the required properties has no atoms.

Comment: @Sean: ah, yes, I should've said what I was actually proving in the finitely additive case. It's probably easier to just stick to the countably additive case to forestall confusion on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Let $i, j$ be positive integers such that $p_i \ne p_j$. Assume without loss of generality that $p_i > p_j$, and let
$$\varepsilon = p_i - p_j.$$

Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}$ is a convergent series, $\lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}{p_k}} = 0$. Let $N$ be a positive integer large enough that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}{p_k} < \varepsilon$, and let us also require $N > i$ and $N > j$. By assumption,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{p_{i + N k}} = \frac{1}{N} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{p_{j + N k}},$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_{j + N k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_{i + N k}} = \left(\frac{1}{N} - p_j\right) - \left(\frac{1}{N} - p_i\right) = p_i - p_j = \varepsilon.$$
But this contradicts the definition of $N$. Indeed,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_{j + N k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_{i + N k}} \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_{j + N k}} \le \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}{p_k} < \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score -2):

What is the problem if $p_n$ is 0 for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?
It would be a problem if $P(S) = 0$ for every $S \subset \mathbb{N}$.
Perhaps you are worried because $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i = 0$, but this is not a problem without $\sigma$-additivity, as Bruno de Finetti suggested.

[A curious paper (unluckily in italian)](http://www.brunodefinetti.it/Opere/massimoComuneDivisore.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. Though I am making the standard assumption that probability distributions are countably additive, it still makes sense to ask my question for finitely additive probability distributions. See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203220/finitely-additive-probability-measure-thats-not-countably-subadditive.

Comment: I suppose that the downvote is caused by the style, I said the same thing Sean Eberhard said: "your argument shows that any finitely additive measure with the required properties has no atom". $1 = P(\mathbb{N}) = P(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} \{ i \})$; $0 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 0 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(\{ i \})$. With $\sigma$-additivity $P(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} \{ i \}) =
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(\{ i \})$, but $1 \neq 0$, so either you refuse uniform distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ (and $\mathbb{Z}$) or you refuse Kolmogorov axioms.

Comment: From BaggioMito's truncated comment (coverted from an answer): "... so people usually refuse uniform distributions on $\mathbb{N}$.
The next step is to refuse Lebesgue measure, I understand the trouble."